# Calculate number of days with momentjs goes wrong

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to calculate the days between two date objects. I found some wired result, so I test simply by subtracting the current date with itself, the result is expected to be 0, but it returns 4, which I cannot explain.

I use momentjs for quite a long time. I trusted the library and its results. What's wrong with the code?

```js
var now = new Date();
var diff = moment(now - now).days();
console.log(diff);
console.log(now - now);
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Update #1:** Really sorry for this silly question. The correct format should be

```
var diff = moment.duration(now - now).days();
```

Comment: `now - now` would always return `0`, and `moment(0)` would evaluate to `Thu Jan 01 1970` that its `days()` is `4 (Thursday)`

Comment: @haim770 he says that `moment(0).days()` gives `4`

Comment: Hi both, your comments are interesting. 4 means Thursday, not the days between two dates...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `now - now` returns `0`, you code is equivalent to:

```
moment(0) // "Thu Jan 01 1970 02:00:00 GMT+0200"
      .days() // 4 is for Thursday
```

You better use `moment.diff()` to get the difference between two dates:

```
var d1 = new Date(),
    d2 = new Date();

var differenceInDays = moment(d1).diff(d2, 'days'); // 0, obviously
```

See [Documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Answer (score 2):

It is the 4 day of week

```
new Date(0) => Thu Jan 01 1970 06:00:00 GMT+0600 // my local timezone
```